# Why does this query work in Sequel Pro but not in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$zips = array('10583','06890','06854');

$list = implode("','",$zips);

$q = "SELECT site_id FROM site_zipcodes WHERE zipcode IN ('%s')";

$result = db_query($q, $list);
```

This query returns no results.

However, a sprintf with the same parameters returns

```
SELECT site_id FROM site_zipcodes WHERE zipcode IN ('10583','06890','06854')
```

and when I put that query into Sequel Pro, I get three results (the expected behavior).

When I use one zipcode in the IN statement, db_query works just fine.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening.

Comment: It's great if `db_query()` works fine when you pass it the complete SQL string. However we cannot tell you what happens when `($q, $list)` doesn't, because you haven't shared your particular db_query function.

Comment: If sprintf generates a valid SQL query, Why don't you `$query = sprintf($q, $list);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Without a definition of the `db_query` function, it's not possible to tell why this isn't working. For debugging this, the `db_query` function could echo (or var_dump) the actual SQL text being sent to the database.

But likely, the SQL produced by the `db_query` function does not include the comma separators in the IN list. The comma separators must be part of the SQL text. Any commas that are passed in as part of a value of a bind parameter are considered to be part of the value.

If we use a prepared statement, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN ( ? )
```

And we supply **`'fee','fi','fo','fum'`** as the value of the bind parameter, that's equivalent to running statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN ( '''fee'',''fi'',''fo'',''fum''' )
```

Such that the query will only return rows where `bar` is equal to that single string. Effectively equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = '''fee'',''fi'',''fo'',''fum'''
```

To search for rows that match one of the values in that list, using a statement with bind parameters, the SQL text would need to be of the form:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN ( ? , ? , ? , ? )
```

The commas need to be part of the actual SQL text. And we'd supply a separate value for each of the four bind parameters.

---

But again, I'm just guessing at what that `db_query` function is doing.